# Capture command line argument and store it

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to capture a command line argument and store it as a string however i get a compiler error when I'm trying to convert it to an int as :

> The error is: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
>   [enabled by default]
>        char test = argv[1];

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

char test = argv[1];
printf("%c\n", test);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to capture the command -f

Comment: The compiler is right, try `char *test = argv[1]; printf("%s\n", test);`.

Comment: argv is a two level pointer of type char. Hence `argv[1]` is a 1 level pointer of type char, which cannot be stored in a simple char.

Comment: and please make sure to check whether you actually have at least 1 command line argument using argc ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`argv[1]` is holding a string and you are trying to store it in character variable what you need is a character pointer

```
char *test = argv[1];
```

and print it

```
printf("%s\n", test);
```